# JQuery Ajax loading file with $.getScript callback passes unkown parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following function needs to load external files and differentiates between simple GET and files that need to use script dataType method.

```
function navegacion(dashboard, history, rtype)
{
     var urlPath = dashboard;
     if(rtype !== 'script') {rtype = 'GET';} else {rtype = 'script';}
     $.ajax({
          type: rtype,
          async:true,
          url: "ajaxapi.php?dashboard="+ dashboard,
          success: function(msg) {
            $("#main-div").html(msg);
          }
     });
}
```

A second file that gets called with the previous function is also loading an external file using the following function:

```
$.holdReady(true);
//set hold

function releaseHold() {
    $.holdReady(false); 
    $('#table').DataTable();
}
//callback to release hold

$.getScript('./javascript/jquery.dataTables.min.js', releaseHold); 
//load script then release hold
```

The problem is that a parameter is being passed to the url like this:
**/javascript/jquery.dataTables.min.js?_=1457117615305**

The parameter changes on each load so it is becoming impossible to cache the file.

How can I fix this? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.getScript` method is a shortcut for calling `$.ajax` with some default options passed in. One of those options is setting `cache: false`, which will append the cache busting parameter you are seeing here.

To remove the cache buster you'll need to call `$.ajax` directly.

```
$.ajax({url: '/url/to/script.js', dataType: 'script', cache: true})
```

See documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: In this particular case I just had to add "success: releaseHold" in order to use the callback